# setOnClickListener of imageView inside recyclerView handling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I had implemented `ListView` which was working perfectly. Each list entry contains `ImageView` and `TextView`. Thumbnail and title.

I implemented `imageView.setOnItemClick()` in `ListviewAdaper` that shows `TextView` and clicking it again on `ImageView` make `TextView` GONE.

Now I moved to `RecyclerView` with same layout (`ImageView` and `TextView`).

In `public void onBindViewHolder()` of my `RecyclerAdaper` have added same code as I was implemented in list view.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    imageview = holder.image;
    textview = holder.text;
    imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (type != MyGlobals.DATA_TYPE1) {
                if (subtitle.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    imageview.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                    textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    imageview.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
                    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    }
```

Problem here is if I have `RecyclerView` entries more than 1, and I click on any `ImageView` entry of any `RecyclerView` entry, only last entrie's `TextView` has become VISIBLE/GONE and not the respective entrie's `TextView`.

When I put on debugger and break at `onClick` of `ImageView`, it actually shows the `TextView` of last entry or `RecyclerView`.

How can I handle each `ImageView` of each `RecyclerView` entry independently  to make respective `TextView` visible/gone?

Just a note I had `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` of each entry also which are working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the approach you're doing is not a very good one because it is creating a new anonymous inner class on every`bindHolder` callback. Which is just a waster of memory and overloading the GC for no good reason.

The actual reason you're having the issue is because you're getting a reference to the image with `image = holder.image;` but then on the next this reference is lost.

With a more separated approach we can deal with both those issues. For that, add this to your ViewHolder

```
  static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

      ImageView imageView;

      public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
         imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
           // do your action here with imageView
      }
   }
```

and then remove all that `click` related code from your `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Each recylclerview entry is (image, title, subtitile, count) which is a separate class object and its list dataList is populated. To access individual entry in onClick (in my case textview), i can get entry by dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()) if needs to operate on perticular list entry.

Comment: Glad it worked. Another way is to add the data instance to the Holder during binding, like `holder.data = dataList.get(position)` so then during on click, it's there, ready to use

Comment: If you have multiple row type `if (imageView != null) imageView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

 holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      // Your image click code

     }
  });

 }
```